# Modern UI app pages life cycle

Tags: c#, windows-8, modern-ui

Is there a way to navigate from `page1` to `page2` and then back to `page1` without loading the page again? (I'm programming in Visual Studio 13 for Windows in C#.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly is your requirement but one way to do it would be to have all your content in one same page and make its chunks visible/invisible in place of navigating anywhere..

Answer (score 0):

The page is not loaded again.
The page (which is actually a user control) get constructed the first time you access it and stay alive until the application close.

The UserControl.Loaded event is called every time the page is ready to be displayed.
Dont let the name fool you: "Loaded" means "I'm ready to start rendering", not "I've loaded XAML from disk and created the logical tree" (which happens once in the InitializeComponent method called from Constructor).